# why vscode is not recognizing react code as react javascript instead it format it as vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using Prettier with format on save enabled 
but when I make any change in App.js and save it
Prettier do destroy my code because it deals with it as plain javascript

Comment: I don't see react in the list of supported languages for prettier, maybe simply this?

Comment: React isn't a language, so that could be it!

Comment: It's common for another installed formatter to take precedence over prettier. Beautify is a common culprit.

Comment: I gave you a general answer since your question is so vague. Update it with more project information and I could provide a better answer.

Comment: kemotoe's comment is important. It's easy to install many 3rd-party extensions with overlapping functionality. Before anything else, one should inspect their VS Code extensions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am using create-react-app so it produce the main component App.js
I am using .JSX in the other components but the problem is when I make any change to the App.js

I fixed this issue by changing the files associations setting in Vscode settings (specific to user workspace)

I just added this line

```
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```

and worked perfectly for me.

Comment: So what happens when you're working in non-React JS files, where you might prefer other formatting?

Comment: you get emmet auto completes in nodejs that's what happens

Comment: @MarsAndBack You can create a directory `/yourproject/.vscode/settings.json` and paste above code there. Also make sure to add this directory in `.gitignore`

Answer (score 4):

rename your react files as 'jsx' files instead of js files and keep your vanilla javascript as js files. This way vs code and prettier know that you are using react-javascript instead of normal javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I don't read anything about react in prettier documentation

As far as I understand, react code should be put in .jsx files, not .js

https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

> React doesn’t require using JSX, but most people find it helpful as a
>   visual aid when working with UI inside the JavaScript code

Comment: It's a personal preference, but most editors will behave better when it's just a `.js` file because it is just a `.js` file

Comment: JS files doesn't have JSX HTML templates inside, so it's not just a JS file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ESlint as well you should follow these steps...

```
  yarn add --dev --exact prettier
  yarn add --dev eslint-plugin-prettier
```

Create a .eslintrc file in the root of your project with the following contents

```
  {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "plugins": ["prettier"],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": "error"
    }
  }
```

That should hopefully do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Prettier checks how your code is *structured* whereas VSCode syntax code highlighting controls how your code *looks*.

VS Code highlights code via extensions, not with Prettier. Out of the box, VS Code supports [React and JSX natively](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript). You also adjust VS Code's `settings.json` file. Here's an example off how that might look:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,

    // Solarized-dark theme
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized-dark",

    // Changes the highlight color in solarized-dark, which I can't see
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "editor.selectionBackground": "#5b455e",
      "editorBracketMatch.border": "#555",
      "editorBracketMatch.background": "#5b455e"
    },

    // Number of spaces in a tab
    "editor.tabSize": 2,

    // Insert spaces when pressing Tab. This setting is overriden
    // based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,

    // Override whatever the files say and give me 2 spaces per tab
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always"
  }
```

Prettier code formatting is usually controlled as part of a server, rolled up into something like Webpack or Parcel as part of a build script. If you're using `create-react-app` I think it's already wired in. If you want to adjust some of the settings, Prettier uses a simple JSON file called `.prettierrc` that belongs in the root of your project.

Example `.prettierrc`:

```
// Relaxes need for semicolons, lints for single quotes and requires trailing commas
{
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5"
}
```